# Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: while creating record in MS CRM 2016 Online Using WCF service as Client

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, dynamics-crm-2013

I using an wcf service to create record in MS CRM 2016. When i consume service by hosting it on localhost i get responce but when i tried to consume after hosting it on IIS it gives above error. Problem is when i execute any CRM operation in service then only it gives above error otherwise it works fine.
`//var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("http://localhost:42078/Service.svc/CreateXML"));
                    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("http://10.103.40.109/Service.svc/CreateXML"));`

Here first commented line works fine but when i try second line it gives error.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to deploy any custom entity?

Comment: no m using contact entity

Comment: Have you already tried putting the 42078 port number after the IP address?

Answer (score 0):

It is the firewall of my server which were causing issue what i just do is add defalut proxy in my wcf service config file under configuration tag. And it solved my issue.

```
    <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy bypassonlocal="True" proxyaddress="http://proxyaddress:port"/>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```